# ignoring some branches git svn fetch

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm working with svn repositories, when i run git svn fetch command i receive error:

```
Found possible branch point: https://svn.host.ru/repo/trunk => https://svn.host.ru/repo/branches/branch_name, 13439
Found branch parent: (refs/remotes/origin/branch_name) a081660107eb24a999957a6874bdf4dd53568436
Following parent with do_switch
Successfully followed parent
fatal: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/remotes/origin/branch_name': refusing to update ref with bad name refs/remotes/origin/branch_name
update-ref -m r13440 refs/remotes/origin/branch_name 5858b0838db06456ae1de9395a46d1d3fe3c2017: command returned error: 128
```

i understand its because name `branch_name` actually something like `~titanbig\-?\d+\.ru` - contains bad symbols - how can i solve this problem? Maybe some options to skip such bad branches?

Comment: did you try to read docs? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#git-svn---ignore-refsltregexgt

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--ignore-paths` switch or the `svn-remote.<name>.ignore-paths` config option. You can give a perl regex there that specifies paths to ignore. For more information see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn.